# Span of a finite set of linearly dependent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that a linear dependent set of $n$ vectors does not span $V$, where $\dim(V)=n$.

For example, show that $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(2,0,0)\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem. A linear dependent set of *n* vectors does not span *V*, where dim(*V*) = *n*.

Proof. Given a linear dependent set of *n* vectors $(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},...,\vec{v_n})$ and a vector space $V$ with $dim(V) = n$, we need to show that there exists at least one $\vec{x}\in{V}$ where the elements in $\vec{x}$ is given by $x_{i}\in{R}$ is not an element of the $span{(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},...,\vec{v_n})}$. Note that the $span{(\vec{v_1},\vec{v_2},...,\vec{v_n})} = \{\lambda_1\vec{v_1}+\lambda_2\vec{v_2}+...+\lambda_n\vec{v_n} : \lambda_i\in{R}\} = $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_{11} & \cdots & \lambda_{1n} \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \lambda_{n1} & \cdots & \lambda_{nn} \\
    \end{bmatrix} = A.
$
If we can show that a vector in $V$ is not in the span of the linear dependent set, then the set does not span $V$.

To show this, first take the augmented matrix: $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_{11} & \cdots & \lambda_{1n} \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \lambda_{n1} & \cdots & \lambda_{nn} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      x_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    x_n \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Since the $det(A) = 0$ there is a row-equivalent matrix such that there exists a row of all zeros. So, $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_{11} & \cdots & \lambda_{1n} \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      x_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    x_n \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Letting $x_n \neq 0$, then there is no solution to the system and therefore there exists at least one vector in $V$ that is not in the span. Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

If there are some $a,b,c\in \Bbb R$ such that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=a(1,0,0)+b(0,1,0)+c(2,0,0)$, then $x_3=0$. Therefore $(0,0,1)$ is not in that span.

Answer (score 0):

$(0,0,1)$ is not in the span of $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(2,0,0)\} $